# What is the amount of nisab for Zakah?

Tags: fiqh, zakat, nisab

What does nisab mean? What is the amount of nisab, how a persone calculate his Zakah ?

Answer (score 5):

Zakat is obligatory charity.

*Nisab* means the minimum amount of wealth, such that if a person owns less than that then Zakat is not obligatory on them.

The Nisab for

- Gold is 85 grams<sup>1</sup> (20 [Dinar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_dinar) = 20 [Mithqal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithqal))

  > عليك شىء - يعني في الذهب - حتى يكون لك عشرون دينارا فاذا كان لك عشرون
  >   دينارا وحال عليها الحول ففيها نصف دينار
  >
  > Nothing is incumbent on you, that is, on gold, till it reaches twenty
  >   dinars. When you possess twenty dinars and one year passes on them,
  >   half a dinar is payable.
  >
  > <sub>— [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/9/18)</sub>
- Silver is 595 grams<sup>2</sup>  ( 200 [Dirhams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirham) = 5 [Uqiyah](https://islamqa.info/en/129635) = 140 [Mithqal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mithqal))

  > فاذا كانت لك مايتا درهم وحال عليها الحول ففيها خمسة دراهم
  >
  > When you possess two hundred dirhams and one year passes on them, five
  >   dirhams are payable.
  >
  > <sub>— [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/9/18)</sub>
- Cash, cash equivalents and Goods for sale is the valuation equal to either of the above which one feels is better. In present times some recommend using the valuation using silver since that will have more people helping others, while others prefer the valuation using gold since less poor people will be burdened with paying it.

There are different thresholds for cattle and produce from agricultural land. Items of use are not subject to Zakat.

Zakat is calculated by taking 2.5% of your net wealth that has remained in your possession for a whole lunar year.

1  <sub>There is a view that this is 87.5 grams ;  also this means the pure metal (24 Karat)</sub> 
2  <sub>There is a view that this is 612.36 grams</sub>

Comment: So there zakat on cash savings of let's say $200? It has to be above nisaab of gold or silver?

Comment: @Ahmed As I said in the answer, there is no correct answer to that. Some scholars prefer gold while others prefer silver. See [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-384#page-1770) ; [islamweb](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/138743/assessing-the-nisaab-of-bank-notes) ; [islamqa](https://islamqa.info/en/2795)